# Использование echo

Tags: php, html

При создании любого сайта обязательно используется HTML код, для построения блоков и построения сайта вообще.

И часто этот код находиться в php файле т.к. нет смысла его выносить в отдельный файл, а потом еще инклудить.

Допустим, есть такой PHP файл, и в нём есть такой код:

```
<?php
$title='Title';
$content='Content//';

echo <<<HTML
<div class='title'>$title</div>
<div class='content'>$content</div>
HTML;

?>
```

Но его можно вывести еще так:

```
<?php
$title='Title';
$content='Content//';
?>

<div class='title'><?echo$title;?></div>
<div class='content'><?echo$content;?></div>
```

В общем, вопрос состоит в том, какой способ лучше использовать? По идее, второй способ должен быть быстрее, но на очень много? Или всё же можно не думать о этом и писать как удобней?

А что например, если через echo выводить много HTML кода?

Answer (score 7):

Ну давайте напишем еще раз.

1. echo во втором случае писать не надо. В РНР есть специальный оператор для вывода:

   ```
   <?=$title?>
   ```
2. В реальном коде есть не только операторы вывода, но также и условные переходы и циклы и вызовы функций. Поэтому HEREDOC в любом случае не вариант.
3. Скорость здесь везде **одинаковая**. И вообще не надо забивать себе голову вопросами "что быстрее". Все те копеечные операции, про которые тебе приходит в голову спросить, по определению не оказывают никакого влияния на скорость исполнения скрипта. А реально важные вещи ты все равно не поймешь, до тех пор пока написание программ для тебя сводится к аккуратному выписыванию операторов в столбик.
4. Выносить HTML отдельный файл **надо**.
5. Причем делать это надо посредством **шаблонизатора**, например Twig или Smarty.

Comment: Насчёт того, что скорость абсолютно одинаковая, я бы поспорил. Оптимизатор у похапэ вряд ли настолько крут. Скорее всего, операции выполняются в лоб. Соответственно, интерполяция строки таки приведёт к созданию лишней строки в памяти. Это не отменяет остальных аргументов, конечно.

Comment: @Kyubey поскольку пых сам по себе не шибко быстрый, то +- 2 миллисекунды особой погоды не сделают. Использование шаблонизаторов тем более скорости не добавит а еще и усугубит ее (в плане скорости, и там будет явно больше 2-х миллисекунд), собственно к этому ответчик и вел.
А насчет использования шаблонизаторов - опять таки, полностью поддерживаю ответчика, в том плане, что лучше учиться правильно и с самого начала разделять вью от исполняемого кода, так будет меньше путаницы и в последующем разных ситуаций в поисках ошибок и масштабировании кода.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую второй вариант во-первых меньше путаницы в коде и не все ideшки хорошо воспринимают код. А во-вторых все же быстрее.